# How safe is it to use old air compressor?

Tags: air-compressor

I have air compressor 91915294 craftsman. I want to use it for spray painting. I bought it use and not sure how old it is. You can see on photos that it has a corrosion but i tried to sand it a bit and it looks like it has good metal under it.

1. Is there a way how to check how safe it is? and what are the chances it blows up?
2. Any recommendations of safe usage of it?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Since i'm scared of my new one, there's no way I would use that one. We have no idea how bad the corrosion _inside_ is. You can get a new tank and keep the compressor. Don't even test it unless you have a huge outdoor area and long cords.

Comment: Does that compressor usually compatible with other tanks?

Comment: Being an older model, it likely has a standard fitting, but you can get collars and adapters to fit a different tank. You can get a large tank from harbor fright for pretty cheap.

Comment: I was about to ask the same question... I have a wimpy oilless compressor that I bought largely because I was tired of bicycle pumps, though it's enough to run low-demand tools like a pinner. But I also have a DeWalt oiled unit which was a curb rescue. (Replaced gauges and some fittings.) No visible rust, but the tank is past its use-by date. I'd been considering whether to try to get a replacement double-tank, take the pump off the cart and get another tank as a nonportable,  or to replace the whole thing with a Harbor Freight disposable...

Answer (score 1):

That exterior rust does not look deep or concerning to me. I would try to repaint it to keep it from spreading, but I wouldn't think it to be a safety hazard.

The interior is my bigger concern. I would unscrew that plug on the bottom and look to see how rusty the interior is.

Answer (score 1):

As @ izzy says it is the corrosion on the inside that is a concern. So if you look inside and find only "limited" rust ,it should be good. The potential problem is that it had water in it when stored. And compressed gas makes some of the biggest accidents.  About a two minute scan with an ultrasonic thickness gauge would be best, that is what industry would do . Maybe you know some one that has one or can find a something on the net. Another conservative possibility is to disconnect that tank and get a new tank ( as noted in the comment by @ Rainmaker.)

Comment: What's the best way to "look inside"? Endoscope camera?

Comment: The best way is UT thickness. The interior appearance is not worth much; one needs to know the remaining steel thickness.

Comment: Hm. Would a welding gas supplier have a UT gauge that they might be willing to run over it, I need to refill a 5lb tank of CO2 soon... Also, what's acceptable thickness, or are we just looking for "no obvious putting"?